# Laravel : How to define route start with prefix @ like medium.com/@{username}?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

How to define route in laravel , which start with prefix @ in web.php

like `myapp.com/@username`

Comment: in route file or in blade

Comment: is @ allowed character for a url ?

Comment: yes , it is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got my answer .

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'User','prefix' => '@{username}'], 
function () {
   Route::get('/','UserController@get_user_profile');
});
```

in User Controller

```
  public function get_user_profile($username){
    $user=User::where('slug',$username)->first();
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use route `group()` to define prefix as -

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '@username'], function () {
        Route::get('/','TestController@test');
});
```

You can access this `url` as `www.base_url.com/@username/`

If you want to set `username` `dynamically` then you could this-

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '@{username}'], function () {
        Route::get('/','TestController@test');
});
```

And in your controller-

```
public function test($username)
{
      echo $username; 
}
```

Comment: please tell in detail , how '@username' prefix works ?

Comment: you have only created a group , but where is URL ?

Comment: No but your URL is now : www.base_url.com/@username/test ....that is not i want , i want this URL : www.base_url.com/@username ....then fetch its profile from database and show

Comment: @ Sohel0415 , wait until i test and reply. , thanks for help.

Comment: Your test route is not working . but i have got my answer.

Comment: use the second one as you are trying to excess the url parameter value dynamically. Updated my answer

Comment: @sohel0415 can you please explain why we use such  @ in our url wat is benifit of its. we also can biuld whout using @.

Comment: @LokendraParihar--Lok here `@` just a string, nothing else